# PostgreSQL-HA on Kubernetes recover from Volume Snapshot?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, persistent-volume-claims

I have a Kubernetes Volume Snapshot created for pgsql-ha persistent volume backup.

Now that I'm able to recover the PVC by specifying the *dataSource* as the volume snapshot, and trying to create a new pgsql-ha cluster using HELM chart, then attach this PCV to recover the data. Following is the example installation command:

```
helm install db-ha bitnami/postgresql-ha\
    --set postgresql.password=$PWD \
    --set persistence.existingClaim="pvc-restore-from-snapshot"
```

Then the *pgpol* and both *postgresql* Pods shows CrashLoopBackOff forever.

```
$ kubectl get pods --watch
NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
db-ha-pgpool-gradfergr43sfxv   0/1     Running            0          8s
db-ha-postgresql-0             0/1     Init:0/1           0          8s
db-ha-postgresql-1             0/1     Init:0/1           0          8s
db-ha-postgresql-1             0/1     PodInitializing    0          23s
db-ha-postgresql-0             0/1     PodInitializing    0          23s
db-ha-postgresql-1             0/1     Error              0          24s
db-ha-postgresql-0             0/1     Error              0          24s
db-ha-postgresql-1             0/1     Error              1          25s
db-ha-postgresql-0             0/1     Error              1          25s
db-ha-postgresql-1             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          26s
db-ha-postgresql-0             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          27s
```

From what I have read so far in **[this issue](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/4623)**, *persistence.existingClaim* is only supported when *replica* was set to 1, which means it can only be restored on a non-ha cluster, and pgsql-ha is currently unable to replicate the manually specified PVC.

So I'm wondering the following:

- If that is the whole story, and there is nothing that I'm missing
- If it's possible to modify the *storageClass* or even the *provisioner* (ebs-csi), so that the existing PVC can be used
- If other workaround exist for this workflow

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The same limitation is also mentioned here. https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7282#issuecomment-903485293

I think you'd probably have to put in a feature request to restore 1 pvc snapshot into multiple replicas. Or maybe a little more challenging, but you could fix the limitation yourself in the chart and submit a pull request.